# Tinymce is not returning HTML but just text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, tinymce-4

I'm struggeling with this problem. I'm very new to javascript i had tinymce v3 for my website working, but i wanted to update it also looked way to complicated. So i installed v4 it took me a while but i finaly got i working. In the sence of its showing the textarea. When i post my page it does not return text with html tags around it but just a string. And when i use blockquotes it just returns a string with
[quote][/quote].
This is the code i use.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){ 

      $(function() { 

          $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({

            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.js")',
            theme: "modern",

            height: "300",
            width: "1150",
            verify_html: true,
            statusbar: true,
            plugins : "pagebreak,bbcode,link,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,thisisnotvaled,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,codehighlighting,netadvimage",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : false,

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            content_css : "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/css/content.css")",
            convert_urls: false,

            // TODO: Make line breaks work and qoutes are now also not working

            force_br_newlines: true,
            force_p_newlines: true,
            forced_root_block: '',
            remove_linebreaks: false,
            convert_newlines_to_br: true,

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js"

        });

      });

    })();

</script>
```

Its also not forcing line breaks i think mainly because its also not returning HTML. i have been searching but i cant find anything concrete. So just to simplyfy it its returning it like this : `Hello world. But i want it like this : <p>hello world</p>`

---

Answer (score 0):

Well that took me a full 24 hours to find out. It was BBcode Plugin. The documentation is not really there for Tinymce. For people that have problems make sure you check you're plugins they can be a real pain in you're ass.